# PHP textContent removing HTML?

Tags: php

I have the following script which loops through a HTML table and gets the values from it then returns the value of the table in a td.

```
$tds = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');

                // New dom
                $dom2 = new DOMDocument;

                $x = 1;
                // Loop through all the tds printing the value with a new class
                foreach($tds as $t) {
                    if($x%2 == 1)
                        print "</tr><tr>";

                    $class = ($x%2 == 1) ? "odd" : "even";

                    var_dump($t->textContent);

                    print "<td class='$class'>".$t->textContent."</td>";
                    $x++;
                }
```

But the textContent seems to be stripping the HTML tags (for example it is a `<p></p>` wrapper tag). How can I get it to just give me the value?

Or is there another way of doing this? I have the following html

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>q1</td>
<td>a1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>q2</td>
<td>a2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and I need to make it look like

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="odd">q1</td>
<td class="even">a1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="odd">q2</td>
<td class="even">a2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It will always look the exact same way (minus extra element rows and the values which change).

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.textContent) this is the expected behaviour of textContent.

You can just add the class to the `td`s in the DomDocument

```
$tds = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
$x = 1;
foreach($tds as $td) {
    if($x%2 == 1){
        $td->setAttribute('class', 'odd');
    }
    else{
        $td->setAttribute('class', 'even');
    }
    $x++;
}
```